# Check if key exists in other table

Tags: sql, key, exists

I want to check if an entry in a column is valid by running it by and checking it other entries in a different table e.g A user enters `"AB"` in column `T1.C1`, I then want to check if `"AB"` exists in column `T2.C2.` Any ideas?

Comment: Do the rows in the two tables have to match in any other way (e.g. the user's id) or is it just "does this value exist somewhere"?

Comment: Is called a ["foreign key"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) and your DBMS can handle it on its own, just *declare* it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to just lookup a value, do a `SELECT` with a `WHERE` clause:

```
select * from T2 where T2.C2 = 'AB'
```

To verify the entire table, you could use `WHERE IN`:

```
select * from T2
where T2.C2 in
(
   select C1 from T1 where T1.C1 = T2.C2
)
```

Another equivalent way of performing the same query is `WHERE EXISTS`:

```
select * from T2
where exists
(
   select * from T1 where T1.C1 = T2.C2
)
```

If you want to see which T1s match with T2s, do an `INNER JOIN`:

```
select * from T1
inner join T2 on T2.C2 = T1.C1
```

If your database schema requires that there is a T2.C2 that matches T1.C1, then you should use a foreign key to assert this requirement.  Depending on which table is the parent and which is the child, the foreign key will look like this:

```
alter table ChidlTable
add constraint FK_Child_Parent foreign key (C1)
references ParentTable (C2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXISTS` to check for existence:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 T1
WHERE T1.C1 = 'AB'
AND EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM Table2 T2 WHERE T2.C2 = T1.C1
)
```